# Return one instance of each different SQLite column

Tags: sql, sqlite

The query I am doing is:

```
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(Formula.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Formula._ID, Formula.CATAGORY }, null, null, null);
```

The problem is that it returns:

```
Algebra
Algebra
Algebra
...
Geometry
Geometry
...
```

How can I query this so that it return just **ONE** of each different column:

```
Algebra
Geometry
```

**UPDATE:**
The query I am running is:

```
SELECT * FROM formula
```

Comment: Provide a list of the columns in the formula table, and some example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from formula;
```

But it is better practice to list out the column names, instead of using the * just in case anything changes.

so it'll look like

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name from formula;
```

But the key really is the DISTINCT keyword.